# Scroll outer tableview with inner tableview and vice versa when headerview reaches top

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uiscrollviewdelegate

I realize variations of this question have been asked, but I'm having trouble connecting the dots into a coherent solution for my problem. So here's my scenario:

> I have a UITableView that has 2 sections. Section 1 has no header view, and 1 cell. Section 2 has a header view (it floats as is the default behavior with plain table views), and 1 cell. This solitary section 1 cell has a horizontally paging scrollview with 3 pages. Each page is a tableview. This sounds a little nutty, but it is totally legal and makes perfect sense. My scenario is a user profile screen. Section 1's cell is the user's bio. Section 2's header is a paging menu that shows the three menu options. The pager has three tableviews for all the content a user publishes, follows, and their posts.

[image]

The problem is that when the user scrolls any of the inner tableviews in the pager, I want the outer tableview to scroll until the bio is scrolled off screen and the section header hits the nav bar of the view controller. And then I want the inner scrollview to take over the scrolling.

I've been playing with a combination of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods: `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` & `shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer`. I am able to either scroll the tableviews simultaneously (which, btw, isn't terrible, but it's definitely not my desired behavior) or just enable scrolling on either the inner or outer tableview. I would love to be able to solve this problem using the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` because my gut tells me that the solution doesn't need to involve any delegation and overriding contentOffsets using `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods like `scrollViewDidScroll:` and so on. But maybe I'm wrong, and I will have to go that route.

Thought I'd throw this up there before I threw in the towel. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you watched any of the advanced table view videos from WWDC in the last few years?  One or two of them dealt in nested scroll views.  I remember solutions using `scrollViewDidScroll:` as you noted, and also some solutions where they transplanted the gesture recognizer of the scroll view.

Comment: @CharlesA. I did a while back. But it seems like it's time to watch them again. :/